# JSON from api request in func app encoded differently to that of a Django app

Tags: python, json, django, python-requests, azure-functions

I have a Django application which contains a function that calls an API and adds the data from the response into my database. I am trying to move this function into an Azure function app, however the JSON that is returned from the request seems to be encoded differently which is causing the database insert to fail.

Request function from Django:

```py
def fetch_magic_set_data(code, max_retries=3, sleep_base=2):
  for retry in range(max_retries):
    try:
      response = requests.get(f'https://mtgjson.com/api/v5/{code}.json')
      response.raise_for_status()
      magic_sets_json = response.json()
      if 'data' in magic_sets_json and 'cards' in magic_sets_json['data']:
        return True, magic_sets_json['data']
      else:
        print(f'Response is empty for {code}, retrying...')
    except HTTPError as http_err:
      print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
    except RequestException as req_err:
      print(f'Request error occurred: {req_err}')
    sleep_time = sleep_base * (2 ** retry)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
  return False, None
```

Request function from function app:

```py
def get_response(url, max_attempts=10):
    for attempt in range(max_attempts):
        try:
            response = requests.get(url)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                return response
            elif 400 <= response.status_code < 600:
                logger.warning(f"Status: {response.status_code}. Error from {url}.")
                if response.status_code == 404:
                    return None
        except requests.RequestException as e:
            logger.warning(f"Attempt {attempt + 1} of {max_attempts}. Error: {e}")
            if attempt < max_attempts - 1:
                time.sleep((2 ** attempt) + (attempt % 2))
            else:
                logger.error(f"Failed to get response from {url} after {max_attempts} attempts.")
                return None
    return None

def fetch_magic_set_data(code):
    url = MTGJSON_API_BASE_URL + code.upper() + '.json'
    response = get_response(url)
    if response:
        try:
            magic_set_data = response.json()
            return magic_set_data['data']
        except ValueError:
            logger.error(f"Failed to parse JSON data from {url}.")
    else:
        logger.error(f"Failed to get a valid response from {url}.")
    return {}
```

If I `print(response.headers['Content-Type'])` returns `application/json` for both

If I `print(response.content)`, part of the response from the Django app is `'type': 'Legendary Planeswalker — Jace',`, however it is `"type": "Legendary Planeswalker \xe2\x80\x94 Jace",` in the function app.

If I add the following code to the function app, the decoded data looks like `"type": "Legendary Planeswalker ù Jace",`

```py
decoded_content = response.content.decode('utf-8')
print(decoded_content)
magic_sets_json = json.loads(decoded_content)
```

Both applications are using `python version 3.10.11` and `requests version 2.31.0`.

How do I get the function app to return the JSON data encoded the same as the JSON data returned from the Django app.

Comment: What happens if you use response.content.decode('utf-8-sig')

Comment: Returns the same as `utf-8`: `"type": "Legendary Planeswalker ù Jace",`

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions Python script designed to make an HTTP request to a given URL, decode the JSON response with proper character encoding, and return the decoded JSON as an HTTP response with content.

- Retrieve JSON data from an external API and return it as an HTTP response

**Code:**

```py
def get_response(url, max_attempts=10):
    for attempt in range(max_attempts):
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, stream=True)  # Use stream=True for streaming
            if response.status_code == 200:
                return response
            elif 400 <= response.status_code < 600:
                Logger.warning(f"Status: {response.status_code}. Error from {url}.")
                if response.status_code == 404:
                    return None
        except requests.RequestException as e:
            LoggerAdapter.warning(f"Attempt {attempt + 1} of {max_attempts}. Error: {e}")
            if attempt < max_attempts - 1:
                time.sleep((2 ** attempt) + (attempt % 2))
            else:
                logger.error(f"Failed to get response from {url} after {max_attempts} attempts.")
                return None
    return None

def decode_json_with_proper_special_characters(content):
    # Replace special characters with their correct encodings
    content = content.replace("—", "\u2014")
    content = content.replace("…", "\u2026")
    # Add more replacements as needed

    return content

def generate_json_response(response):
    try:
        content = ""
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                decoded_content = chunk.decode('utf-8', errors='replace')  # Replace problematic characters
                decoded_content = decode_json_with_proper_special_characters(decoded_content)
                content += decoded_content
        return content
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error while streaming and processing: {str(e)}")



def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    code = req.params.get('code')

    if not code:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please provide a 'code' parameter in the query string.",
            status_code=400
        )

    url = f'https://mtgjson.com/api/v5/{code}.json'
    response = get_response(url)

    if response:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            generate_json_response(response),  # Streaming response content
            mimetype='application/json',
        )
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse("Failed to get a valid response from the API.", status_code=500)
```

**Output:**

[image]